# One Storyboard for multiple triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-animation

Context: I have two `Storyboards` in my `UserControl`. One of them is for sliding the UserControl in and one is for sliding it out.

All I'm doing for the slide in/out is setting the margin to a negative value for sliding out and to zero for sliding in.

Now, I want the `sbShowLeftMenu` storyboard to be executed when the `UserControl`'s visibility is set to `Visible`. Also, I want to be able to manually slide the `UserControl` in/out using the Buttons `BtnHide` & `BtnShow`.

Now if the UserControl becomes visible the `sbShowLeftMenu` is activated and the UserControls gets moved in. Switching the visibility between `Collapsed` and `Visible` this behaviour continues, as I want it to.

Now if I hit the `BtnHide` to move the UserControl out of viewport everything works fine until I start switching the Visibility of the UserControl again. Now the Storyboard doesn't work anymore. I can still move the UserControls in/out with the Buttons but the 'Visible' Trigger does not start the Storyboard.

Here are gif examples of the behavior:

With the click on 'Database Search' I set the Visibility of the UserControl to Visible (because its bound to the 'IsExpanded' property of the ExpanderControl) and it works just fine:

[image: Example GIF]

Here I demonstrate what happens after I manually click the 'BtnHide':

[image: Demonstration GIF]

This is the code for the UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="10"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Margin" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <Storyboard x:Key="sbShowLeftMenu">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="BtnShow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="BtnHide" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlLeftMenu"  From="-650,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" DecelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="sbHideLeftMenu">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="BtnHide" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="BtnShow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="pnlLeftMenu" From="0,0,0,0" To="-650,0,0,0" AccelerationRatio=".9" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>

        <Grid Background="Red">
            <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="2" Name="pnlLeftMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-650,0,0,0" Height="500">
                <!-- Content -->
                <Border>The Content is in here</Border>
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="BtnShow" Height="25" Width="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Path Stroke="Black"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Data="M 0,0 L 0.5,0.5 L 0,1"
                          Stretch="Uniform"></Path>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sbShowLeftMenu}"></BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="BtnHide" Height="25" Width="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="Collapsed" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <Path Stroke="Black"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Data="M 1,1 L 0.5,0.5 L 1,0"
                          Stretch="Uniform"></Path>
                        </Button.Content>
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource sbHideLeftMenu}"></BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsVisible"
             Value="True" 
             my:TriggerTracing.TriggerName="BoldWhenMouseIsOver"
             my:TriggerTracing.TraceEnabled="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="sbShowLeftMenu" Storyboard="{StaticResource sbShowLeftMenu}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="xy" Storyboard="{StaticResource sbHideLeftMenu}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some **complex** logic which is interfering with the operations of the story boards.

I would recommend that you not try do this in triggers but instead in code behind. Create a **state machine** operation and then open/close/make visible/make invisible depending on the state.

---

The following code is what I use for similar logic of moving a panel based on boolean state via storyboards. You can expand it to handle visibility as well with other states.

```
private bool moveRight = true; // Start out on the left side, then move right.

public void MoveRight()
{
     try
     {
     if (moveRight)
        {
             (Resources["MoveToOpen"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
             (Resources["FlipArrowClose"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
        }
        else
        {
            (Resources["MoveToClose"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
             (Resources["FlipArrowOpen"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
     moveRight = !moveRight;
 }
```